# Flutter running with Xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter

Running the code with Xcode getting error, it works fine in Android Studio running with iOS Simulator but not from Xcode

```
/bin/sh:/Users/modistabox/Documents/karthik/flutter_plugin/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: Operation not permitted
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-IN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

Comment: Can you try checking run script only when installing option in Xcode under Build Phases > Run Script

Comment: now if got this error. /bin/sh: /Users/modistabox/Documents/karthik/flutter_plugin/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: Operation not permitted
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code